# pip install requests or any packages gives SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: python, ssl, pip

i use Python version 3.10 now, and every time i want to install modules using PIP i get:

```
*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/requests/*
```

after a lot of reading and trying i have found that PIP has moved away from ssl to tls.
I have tried to downgrading PIP to 9.0.3 and the i can use PIP as normal. But when i need some special packages, then i need a newer PIP version. so I'm stocked.

I then tried to work on the windows server 2012, to force it to use tls 1.2, by using tool IIS Crypto from Nartac and also by using powershell to disable/enable

running this:

```
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1)
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_1)
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_2)
print(ssl.HAS_TLSv1_3)

gives:
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
True
True
True
True
```

so do i need to set anything in python or at the server?

Comment: The error might not be caused by a wrong TLS version but by the attempt to interpret something as TLS which isn't. This might for example be caused by a wrong proxy configuration, like specifying a `https://` URL for the proxy instead of `http://`. Do you have any proxies configured? If yes, what are the settings?

Comment: yes it is behind proxy. I have both set the http & https, and also set the php.ini, with trusted-host and the proxy http://internetproxy.domain.local:8080.

Comment: What method have you used to specify the proxy. Please provide the settings for both http_proxy and https_proxy. Please make sure to correctly provide the actual schema used in the proxy specification, i.e. `http://proxy:port` vs. `https://proxy:port`.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for your initial help. your question got me thinking about proxy setup outside python. I found that if I have proxy set in  IE or firefox and stopped this, the pip starts working.